# Problems with mysqldbcompare utility. Database consistency check fails every time

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, consistency

I am trying to compare two local databases using the mysqldbcompare utility. The check always shows database consistency check fails. I have tried check and repair command. But to no avail.

I have used the following code and get

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench CE 5.2.47\utilities>mysqldbcompare --s
erver1=root@localhost --server2=root@localhost ebookshop:ebookpub --run-all-tests

# server1 on localhost: ... connected.
# server2 on localhost: ... connected.
# Checking databases ebookshop on server1 and ebookpub on server2
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- ebookshop
+++ ebookpub
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-CREATE DATABASE `ebookshop` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
+CREATE DATABASE `ebookpub` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */

# WARNING: Objects in server1.ebookshop but not in server1.ebookpub:
#        TABLE: books
#
# WARNING: Objects in server1.ebookpub but not in server1.ebookshop:
#        TABLE: books1
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Database consistency check failed.
#
# ...done
```

I am fairly new to this area. Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's failing because there are differences in your databases.

1. One's named `ebookpub` and `ebookshop` respectively.
2. `ebookshop` has table `books`; `ebookpub` has `book1`

Basically it's working as you'd expect.  So "failed" isn't a bad thing.

And you're appropriately using the flag `--run-all-tests` so, it will show you all failures without stopping at the first one.

Comment: Thanks Emile. I just wanted to know one more thing. mysqldbcompare is capable of generating synchronization scripts right.? If there are differences and I want to synchronize the databases, how would I go about it.?

Comment: @user2339071, not sure if you can use `mysqldbcompare` for syncing. i don't think so but you can give the ref page a second look: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/mysqldbcompare.html.  Otherwise, MySQL Workbench works at least for Schema synchronization (and I believe for data too). It's free.

Comment: seems kind of stupid that naming of the database breaks mysqldbcompare when testing 2 local database which for obvious reasons can't have the same database name